# Unable to uninstall Firefox Quantum from my Windows

Tags: windows-10, firefox

I am very sorry to say that but Firefox is getting really annoying, I've installed the last version of Firefox quantum,now that I want to remove it because I made my chrome browser the default browser but Firefox still opens whenever I click on a link. Firefox however refuses to remove itself. I have Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit. When I go to Apps & features, find Firefox and click uninstall nothing happens ! I went to the installation directory, opened uninstall directory, and started help.exe but this programs refuses to open or do what so ever. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Go to Programs folder in C drive and delete the Firefox directory.

Comment: 1, close the all Firefox Tab.
2, Click the Windows Start button
3, In the Start Menu, Select Settings.
4, In Settings select System and then Apps& Features.
5, The list of currently installed programs select Mozilla Firefox.
6, To begin the Uninstall click the Uninstall.

Comment: @vembutech Doesn't work, this is what I am trying to explain :)

Comment: I have Successfully Uninstalled the Firefox in my laptop above steps  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffG1d.png

Comment: @vembutech Good for you, doesn't work for me :)